# 48 or 48,048 KHz?

Tags: location-recording

What do you think is better for shooting in 23,976 fps?
The recorder is a SD 788T if you wanna know

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A better question might be, "What is the final delivery format?" There are a number of workflows where it's more efficient to record at standard 48k and an audio framerate of 29.97/25 fps if the final delivery is either of those formats respectively.

I'd suggest talking with whoever is going to be editing to work out what's the most efficient for post-production.

**Edit:**

Should have mentioned that you only want to use 48.048 if you're shooting in true 24 going to 29.97 in post. [Check out this article for a full explanation](http://www.trewaudio.com/audioflow/2007/03/19/48048-khz/).

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it unless post asks you to do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Stick to 48 kHz.